# Eclipse says "apache is not a member of package org"

Tags: eclipse, scala, cassandra, apache-spark

I am using Scala on Eclipse Luna and trying to connect to Cassandra. My code is showing the error `apache object is not a member of package org` on the following line:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
```

I already imported the Scala and Spark libraries into the project. Does someone know how can I make my program import Spark libraries?

Comment: "I already imported scala and spark libraries into the project. "  It looks like you didn't. Re-check this.

Comment: Would you please share your build configuration (SBT, I guess)? If there's nothing wrong with it, perhaps you have to manually tell your IDE to reload it.

Comment: here are the version I'm using: scala.version: 2.10.4, spark-1.3.0
cassandra-driver: 2.1.5, Is this what you need?